# Bridged cast in ARC and cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I'm learning cocos2d with some books, namely book by Pablo Ruiz, here is some code:

```
[next runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime
                 actionWithDuration:2], 
       [CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:1],
    [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:2],
     [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(cFadeAndShow:data:) 
                                                    data:images],nil]];


- (void) cFadeAndShow: (id)sender data:(void*) data
    {
        NSMutableArray *images = data;
        [self fadeAndShow:images];

    }
```

And it gives me an error showing on data:images in runAction:

```
Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type 'NSMutableArray *' to C pointer type 'void *' requires a bridged cast
```

I tried fixing it to no avail. What should I do? I tried changing void* to NSMutableArray, still didn't help. How do I bridge cast? I tried using `__bridge` but it says that you can't bridge cast NSMutableArray.

Comment: consider using CCCallBlock instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing this call :

```
[CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(cFadeAndShow:data:) data:images],nil]];
```

with this:

```
[CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(cFadeAndShow:data:) data:(__bridge void*)images],nil]];
```

Then in your fade and show method, cast it back to an id:

```
NSMutableArray *images = (__bridge id) data;
```

Comment: This is inherently unsafe! If images is deallocated while the sequence runs, this will crash. If the sequence is stopped before the call func selector ran, and you used bridge transfer/retain to prevent a crash, the images object will leak. CCCallBlock is the safe way to execute a function under ARC.